# Can I change CPU mode to read memory?

Tags: c++, assembly, memory, cpu

Can I programmatically change the CPU modes? (For example, from protected mode to real mode.)

I want to read tmemory in `Visual Studio` but I get an access error. (Because the processor is in protected mode?)

How can I do this?

Comment: Whatever your actual problem is, you are more than likely looking for a solution in the wrong direction. Why do you want to execute code in real mode? What code did you run and what error did it give you? An access error means that you have undefined behavior somewhere in your program. It does not mean that you have to change a processor mode. It means that you have to fix the error causing undefined behavior in your code. Please post a [repro].

Comment: is there any code you worked on? you have to provide some code here... what have you done so far?

Comment: You can't change CPU modes. Maybe you can use `ReadProcessMemory`, depending on what you wanted to do.

Comment: This sounds very much like a [X/Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: You can, but you need to be in ring 0, i.e. you need to be inside the operating system.  It's just a matter of updating `cr0`.

Comment: @fuz: If you change to real mode, windows will no longer be running (on that CPU).  Expect your system to crash spectacularly.  So technically yes you could in theory, but practically no.

Comment: @PeterCordes The question was whether it is possible, not whether it makes sense.  Though I recon, if you disable interrupts while doing these shenanigans, changes are you might just survive it.

Comment: @fuz: yeah possibly, if Windows on other cores doesn't get messed up by whatever you do.  The question kind of has 2 aspects: the title question, and also the part about accessing memory "in Visual Studio".  Anyway sure, yes worth pointing out it's technically possible.

Answer (score 3):

To switch to real mode, your code must:

- have high enough privilege ("CPL = 0"). This mostly restricts it to "kernel only" for most operating systems (e.g. Windows).
- be running in memory that can be accessed in real mode (in the first 1 MiB of the physical address space). Otherwise as soon as you enter real mode you will crash because the CPU can't access your code.

For all cases where it is possible to switch to real mode to access memory (and possible to access the memory from real mode); it's also possible to access memory without switching to real mode (e.g. alter segments and/or page tables) with less hassle and higher performance.

Comment: The second part is incorrect: if you switch back to real mode, the segment caches are not updated, so until `CS` is reloaded, your code executes just as it did before.  That's why you usually see mode changes followed by far jumps to update `CS`.  Indeed, keeping segment registers at the values they had in protected mode was a fairly common technique to implement DOS extenders back in the day.

Comment: @fuz: The 2nd part is saying that instead of changing to real mode (and reloading segment regs with anything), you can instead change page tables in protected mode (and `invlpg` if necessary) to do the same thing.  Or maybe change GDT entries (and reload segment regs) in the unusual case that protected mode wasn't just using flat segments.

Comment: @fuz: If you clear the "protected mode enabled" flag in CR0 but CS is not "16-bit default code size, base address on paragraph boundary <= 0xFFFF0"; then you are not in real mode (it's a bizarre intermediate state half way between protected mode and real mode). Keeping (one or more) data segment registers at values they had in protected mode was common (and this intermediate state was often called "unreal mode" to distinguish it from real mode). Leaving CS at values it had in protected mode has never been common (excluding any "16-bit protected mode" cases where the values are compatible).

Comment: @Brendan You are in real mode if you do that, it's just that your CS selector caches contain values that are impossible to achieve using just real mode.

Comment: @fuz: That's an absurd leap of dodgy logic - "values impossible in real mode" are impossible in real mode (and therefore if you do have "values impossible in real mode" you can not be in real mode).

Comment: @Brendan The CPU is in real mode as soon as the PM bit is clear in CR0.  That's all that matters.

Comment: @fuz: No, there's intermediate states that are neither real mode nor protected mode  (nor long mode).

Comment: @Brendan Where can I read about these states in the Intel manual?  Note that changing the operation mode doesn't really do anything right here and now.  It merely affects what happens when a far jump occurs or a segment register is reloaded.

Comment: @fuz: You can't; they're not intentional, not officially supported (and not even named). You can only read about the officially supported modes and the example code showing how to switch between them.

Comment: @Brendan That's because these modes don't exist!  They are just real mode or protected mode before any update to segment registers.  There's nothing special about that, except perhaps a misunderstanding about how operation modes work on x86.

Comment: @fuz: Where can I read about "real mode includes things that are impossible in real mode" in the Intel manual?

Comment: @Brendan Things that are impossible in real mode are impossible in real mode.  This does not include having state carry over into real mode that cannot be achieved from inside real mode.  Perhaps read the documentation on what entering or leaving real mode actually does and what the effect of changes to the segment registers is.

Comment: @fuz: The fact is that Intel designed real mode to be compatible with older CPUs (80186), and described steps to switch from protected mode to real mode that ensures CS is 16-bit and all segment limits are 64 KiB. Claiming anything else is real mode goes against Intel's intention and Intel's example code.

Comment: @fuz: Note that while I am not able to conclusively prove my assertions using Intel's manual, you are also not able to conclusively prove your assertions using Intel's manual. It comes down to "personal definitions", where both history (e.g. the use of unofficial names like "unreal mode" and "big real mode") and the Intel manual lean towards my definition.

Comment: @fuz: "real mode" with segment base/limit registers still set from protected mode is called "unreal mode".  It's apparently hard to use for CS because returning from interrupts will write CS the normal way (not restoring the internal regs.)  But for other segments, it's apparently somewhat durable.  Documentation: https://wiki.osdev.org/Unreal_Mode

Comment: @PeterCordes I am aware of that moniker.  However, as you said, unreal mode is just what some people call real mode without all segment registers having been changed, so it's not a separate mode at all.  I think the key confusion is that Brendan understood my “impossible to achieve using just real mode” remark as meaning “impossible in real mode,” whereas I meant that you need to do some setup outside of real mode to have these values while in real mode and once you load any segment registers, you have to redo the setup to get that state back.

Comment: @fuz: The only confusion is how real mode is defined (e.g. whether "intentional failure to follow Intel's steps to switch to real mode, resulting in a state that has never been officially supported" does, or does not, meet the definition of "real mode").